# Unable to find web element in Span Tag

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have following in my html :

```
<span class="login-link">Log in</span>
```

I have following code :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login > span")).click();
```

I tried `xPath`, `cssSelector` and `id`, but nothing seems working.

Can you please help.

Comment: Wat do you mean by *nothing seems working*? Share exception log

Comment: Share all the html you are using to build your selector.

Comment: I am assuming you have login div with id login and you are trying to refer its first element using this

Comment: post your complete html. it would be easy to understand for other peers to review and understand your question

Comment: Thank you all. I just ignored to add implicit wait. It's working fine now! Such a simple thing i forgot. Sorry to trouble your valuable time..

Answer (score 1):

You can use this xpath :- `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Log in']")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

You can select your element using class selector as well.

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".login-link")).click();
```

hash (#) is used for referring id in css js. You have to use dot(.) for directly referencing the element.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared and your *code trial* you can use either of the line of code to find the `<span>` tag :

- *cssSelector* :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login > span.login-link")).click();
  ```
- *xpath* :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("span[@class='login-link' and contains(.,'Log in')]")).click();
  ```